# Apply a function to every item in a list

Tags: python

I have the following code for pygame but it applies generally to python

```
expl_sounds = []
for snd in ['expl3.wav', 'expl6.wav']:
    expl_sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, snd)))
```

i would like to mute all items in the list individually instead of muting the entire application or mixer. I tried the following:

```
 for i in expl_sounds:
     expl_sounds[i].set_volume(Sound_Volume)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Sound
```

I dont get the error message. The i in the loop is an integer and the mixer.set_Volume is a valid operation for the elements

What would be the correct way to iterate and apply the volume to each element ?

Comment: You can do as for i in range(expl_sounds)

Comment: @starboy_jb `range(len(expl_sounds))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from your misunderstanding of the syntax `for i in expl_sounds`. *The i in the loop is an integer* isn't true, `i` is one element of the `expl_sounds`, a `pygame.mixer.Sound` instance that you just add before

---

So use the object directly

```
for sound in expl_sounds:
    sound.set_volume(Sound_Volume)
```

To do it by indices, do

```
for i in range(len(expl_sounds)):
    expl_sounds[i].set_volume(Sound_Volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `for i in expl_sounds:`, you are iterating on the elements in `expl_sounds`, so you can just do:

```
for i in expl_sounds:
     i.set_volume(Sound_Volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "i" in "for i in expl_sounds" is the sound object itself, not the array index.

Try the following:

```
for i in expl_sounds:
     i.set_volume(Sound_Volume)
```